# INDEX MATCH and looking in another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, indexing, match, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

I have the formula below which is supposed to look in the current sheet in the cells ($A$7:$B$7), ($A$8:$B$8) and so on. I am then trying to get Excel to look at those cells and their value and then look in the sheet named `Names` to see if there is a match between the range specified.

```
=INDEX(Names!$A$2:$C$4,MATCH(H6,Names!$A$7:$B$7)^(H7,Names!$A$8:$B$8)^(H8,Names!$A$9:$B$9)^(H9,Names!$A$10:$B$10),0)
```

I know that the formula above is not working and that Excel is looking in the range `$A$7:$B$7` in the sheet named `Names`, not in the current sheet. However I do not know how to alter it to do what I have specified.

PS. Although using this formula looks pointless for the size of the spreadsheet it is just a test before applying this to a much larger spreadsheet.

Any help on how to fix this would be really helpful.

I have attached two pictures to illustrate where the formula is used and what it is used for.

The sheet with the names on it:

[image: The sheet with the names on it]

The sheet with the formula on it:

[image: The sheet with the formula on it]

Comment: What are the carets supposed to do in your `Match` formula?

Comment: Its supposed to match any one of those criteria, i.e. it can either match the value in H6, or H7)

Comment: Oh woah, that's cool - I didn't know you could do that with Index/Match, thanks for that! (Unfortunately I am not sure how to help with your issue, but will think about it!)

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult to explain. I said in the description that the ranges ($A$7:$B$7) ($A$8:$B$8) are supposed to reference cells in the current sheet to get the values , but they do not, they reference cells in the 'Names' sheet which means that the formula is wrong. I need to get the formula to look in the cells above in the current sheet and then use the values in those cells as the ranges in the Names sheet.

Comment: Here is a better description of what i want the formula to do. 

Basically i write Name1. The formula takes Name1 (as H6) and then looks at the cells A7&B7 in the current sheet (the one without the names on it). The values in the cells A7&B7 which in this case is B2 and B4 should then be used as the range of cells that should be looked at in the Names sheet to see if the text Name1 which I entered is a match.

Comment: currently however it does not use the values in the cells A7&B7 but simply takes these cells as the range is should use in the Names sheet thus not finding the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, this looks to be what you are looking for:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("names!"&A6&":"&B6),MATCH(H6,IF(H7=INDIRECT("names!"&A8&":"&B8),INDIRECT("names!"&A7&":"&B7)),0))
```

Your going to need to enter this with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**. Note that I also changed the values found in A6:B8 to encompass the whole range on the "names" sheet.

[image]

Comment: Although this works for one match I need to allow it to search using multiple criteria. I have just tried using it for multiple ones and it doesn't like it.

Comment: Also when i tried the above it seemed to return 2. I think its because its counting the number of cells it has looked at (being 2, A7 and B7)

Comment: It returned 2 because that is where the match was.

Comment: OK. so if I wanted it to, instead of returning 2, return the First name that matches the surname entered how would I do that.

Comment: So you want OR criteria? Return the surname if it matches Name1 OR 15/04/2011?

Comment: Sorry man. I just don't get it. In this case Name1 would return somename1, but 15/04/2011 would return somename3

Comment: I see your point, what would I do if I was going to use and then. Just for future reference. So it would have to match all of the criteria.